# Convergence analysis of quadratically convergent phase for Newton method in Boyd & Vandenberghe's Convex Optimization

Tags: convergence-divergence, convex-optimization, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson

On Page 490 of B & V's [Convex Optimization book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf), by the Lipschitz condition (9.31), we have, for $t\ge 0$,

$$\tag{1}
\left\|\nabla^{2} f\left(x+t \Delta x_{\mathrm{nt}}\right)-\nabla^{2} f(x)\right\|_{2} \leq t L\left\|\Delta x_{\mathrm{nt}}\right\|_{2}
$$
and therefore
$$\tag{2}
\left|\Delta x_{\mathrm{nt}}^{T}\left(\nabla^{2} f\left(x+t \Delta x_{\mathrm{nt}}\right)-\nabla^{2} f(x)\right) \Delta x_{\mathrm{nt}}\right| \leq t L\left\|\Delta x_{\mathrm{nt}}\right\|_{2}^{3}
$$
My question is how to get (2) from (1). It seems that, after mutiplying $\left\|\Delta x_{\mathrm{nt}}\right\|_{2}^{2}$ on both sides of (1), applying Cauchy-Schwartz inequality on the lefthand side is a good thought, but the basic Cauchy-Schwartz inequality is only applicable for dot product between two vectors. What can we do now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property that $\|Ax\|_2\leq\|A\|_2\|x\|_2$.
In particular,
\begin{align}
\|x^\top A x\| = \|x^\top (Ax)\| \leq \|x\| \|Ax\|\leq \|x\|\|A\|\|x\| \leq tL \|x\|^3
\end{align}
using the given bound on $A = \nabla^2 f(\bar{x} + tx) - \nabla^2 f(\bar{x})$.

Comment: What is this property? This is exactly what I need, but does it hold?

Comment: The induced operator norm is a sub-multiplicative matrix norm; see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm)

Comment: Yes, your answer makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot.